# Issues making AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook

I am using Facebook messenger webview to display a form, onsubmit, I want to send messages back to the user and also close the webview. My problem now is that the webview/browser closes without sending the messages. I don't know what the problem might be here, this is my code:

```
                function closeWebview() {
                    MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser(function success() {
                        console.log('closed')
                    });
                }

                function sendMessage() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/test-message',
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log('request sent');

                        }
                    })
                }
                sendMessage()
                closeWebview()
```

Comment: Do you want to wait until the AJAX operation completes before closing the web view?  It seems like the commented-out code did exactly that.

Comment: i dunno, but shouldnt you send any data with the post?

Comment: @David No I don't want to wait. I want it to be simultaneous. But it seems the 'closing of webview' is taking precedence.

Comment: @radioactive: Well, if the browser which initiates the AJAX request is closed then I would expect the request to be canceled.  There's nothing ensuring that the request took place or completed successfully.  You need to wait for the request to complete (successfully or unsuccessfully) before you abandon it.

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` stands for *Asynchronous JavaScript And XML*, so, the issue is that `closeWebview` is called before `sendMessage` call is finished.

The solution is to use a `callback` function.

```
function sendMessage(callback) {
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/test-message',
            success: function (data) {
               callback(data);
            }
         })
}
sendMessage(function(data){
  console.log(data);
  closeWebview()
});
```